# navigation Controller button left

Tags: iphone

In my application, i have some leftBarbutton of the navigation bar set to " retour" and some others set to "back" i would like to set all my buttons to "retour", how to do this please ? i have spend many hours to dos this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you want to change the language, rather than the button description itsself.

In oder to change the language have a look into the (appname)-Info.plist.
There is an Attribute: Localization native development region.

Change it accordingly to, i guess in your case France if. am not horribl wrong.

Cheers,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
[btn setTitle:@"retour" forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
btn.frame=CGRectMake(3, 2, 53, 30);
UIBarButtonItem *btnBack=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=btnBack;
[btnBack release];
[btn release];
```